# SignalR across domains: errors with not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, signalr

Trying to call signalR from another domain, and keep on getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   localhost:62150/signalr/negotiate?_=1362242757692. Origin
>   localhost:4982 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
$(function () {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:62150/signalr';
    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () { alert("Now connected!"); })
        .fail(function () { alert("Could not Connect!"); });
});
```

jquery and jquery.signalr.js are loaded, localhost:62150/signalr/hubs responds with JS, localhost:62150/signalr/hubs/negotiate?_=1362243021215 returns JSON if I run this in browser - so its not a missing script or invalid path issue.

What I've tried:

- http://coding4life.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/making-cross-domain-calls-in-signalr/
  (setting jQuery.support.cors and $.connection.hub.url)
- Adding custom header in web.config with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"
  (this works only in IIS ? )
- Creating an http module that would return this header on every request. Also tried to return actual domain name instead of *.

And combinations of all of the above.

Anyone has any idea what else I can try ?

The serving app is a combination of MVC and WebAPI (don't think it makes any difference).
If I'm trying that code from same domain - it works.

Comment: What browser are you using to test this? Does it support CORS?

Comment: Chrome. I can do a cross-domain calls to Web Api via ajax, so yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using 1.0 or higher have you enabled cross domain on the server? (it's disabled by default now)

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });
```

Comment: previous versions were pre-release, and SignalR 1.0 is the first RTM one, so that's not a breaking change ;-)

Comment: FWIW this change is prominently mentioned in the release notes under "1.0 Breaking Changes". https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md is the best place to look for changes in each release.

Comment: I got the error above even I have this line of code. If I use RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() instead, I will get 304. My code is working with IE10 and FF 20, but not with Chrome 25.0.1364.172. Any idea?

Comment: I get this output:
...\Global.asax.cs(17,64,17,81): error CS0117: 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'EnableCrossDomain'
...\Global.asax.cs(17,13,17,91): error CS0619: 'System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration)' is obsolete: 'Use IAppBuilder.MapSignalR in an Owin Startup class. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320578 for more details.'

Answer (score 3):

After wasting a couple of hours I think it's good to share my experience:

1. **DO NOT** add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to your web.config (yes it never sais to add it, but when trying things this is literally the first I did and left it there after a simple jquery cross-domain access test)
2. `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs( new HubConfiguration() { EnableCrossDomain = true } );` works just fine for classes inheriting Hub
3. `RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<MyConnection>( "foo", "/foo", new ConnectionConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true } );` this works just fine too for classes inheriting PersistentConnection